# Функция get, которая получает объект и путь к вложенному свойству объекта и возвращает значение этого свойства

Tags: javascript, объекты

Напишите функцию get, которая получает объект и путь к вложенному свойству объекта и возвращает значение этого свойства (или undefined, если свойства не существует). Третий, опциональный аргумент функции — значение по умолчанию, которое возвращается, если значения по указанному пути не существует.

```
function get(obj, path, defaultValue) {
    // your code here
}

const obj = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c: 'd' 
    },
    e: 'f'
  }
};

get(obj, 'a.b');   // { c : 'd' }
get(obj, 'a.b.c'); // 'd'
get(obj, 'a.e');   // 'f'
get(obj, 'a.x.e'); // undefined
get(obj, 'a.x.e', true); // true
get(obj, 'a.x.e', 'My default value'); // My default value
```

Comment: Как задать хороший вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: А что должно возвращать, например, `get(obj, 'a.__proto__')`? `{}` или `undefined`?

Answer (score 4):

```js
function deepFind(o, str, defaultValue) {
  const keys = str.split('.');
  let current = o;
  while (keys.length > 0) {
    const k = keys.shift();
    if (k in current) {
      current = current[k];
    } else {
      return defaultValue;
    }
  }
  return current;
}

function get(...args) {
  console.log(deepFind(...args));
}

const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 'd'
    },
    e: 'f'
  },
  z: [{a: 'hello'}]
};

get(obj, 'a.b'); // { c : 'd' }
get(obj, 'a.b.c'); // 'd'
get(obj, 'a.e'); // 'f'
get(obj, 'z.0.a'); // 'f'
get(obj, 'a.x.e'); // undefined
get(obj, 'a.x.e', true); // true
get(obj, 'a.x.e', 'My default value'); // My default value
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function get(obj, path, defaultValue = undefined) {
  arr = path.split('.');
  result = obj;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] in result) {
      result = result[arr[i]];
    } else {
      result = defaultValue;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
}


const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 'd'
    },
    e: 'f'
  }
};

get(obj, 'a.b'); // { c : 'd' }
get(obj, 'a.b.c'); // 'd'
get(obj, 'a.e'); // 'f'
get(obj, 'a.x.e'); // undefined
get(obj, 'a.x.e', true); // true
get(obj, 'a.x.e', 'My default value'); // My default value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get(obj, path, defaultValue) {
    const keys = path.split(".");
    const go = (acc, v) => (acc === undefined) ? acc : acc[v];
    const res = keys.reduce(go, obj);
    return (res === undefined) ? defaultValue : res;
}

const obj = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c: 'd' 
    },
    e: 'f'
  }
};

get(obj, 'a.b');   // { c : 'd' }
get(obj, 'a.b.c'); // 'd'
get(obj, 'a.e');   // 'f'
get(obj, 'a.x.e'); // undefined
get(obj, 'a.x.e', true); // true
get(obj, 'a.x.e', 'My default value'); // My default value
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = { red: { big: { apple: 'currentValue' } } };
const str = 'red.big.apple';

    const get = (path, obj, defaultValue) =>
      path
        .split('.')
        .reduce(
          (acc, itemStr) => (acc[itemStr] ? acc[itemStr] : defaultValue),
          obj
        );
    
    console.log(get(str, obj, 'null')); // currentValue
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]