# Задача на вложенность объектов

Tags: javascript, объекты, рекурсия, методы, key

Подскажите пожалуйста , как решить подобную задачку ? ( была на собеседовании )
Не пойму, что делает последний аргумент ?
Попытался получить конечный ключ, но промежуточный не могу, что бы их поэтапно сравнить со строковым значением

upd. задачка решена, спасибо всем , кто откликнулся !

```
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 'c',
    },
  },
  d: 'd',
};

const get = (obj, str, def = null) => {


};

console.log(get(obj, 'a.b.c')); // 'c'
console.log(get(obj, 'a.c', 0)); // 0
console.log(get(obj, 'a.e')); // null
```

```js
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 'c',
    },
  },
  d: 'd',
};

const get = (obj, str, def = null) => {

// начало моего кода
  let arrFromStr = str.split('.');

  const result = [];

  for (let prop in obj) {
    const value = obj[prop];

    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      result.push(get(value));
    } else {
      result.push(value);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(get(obj, 'a.b.c')); // 'c'
console.log(get(obj, 'a.c', 0)); // 0
console.log(get(obj, 'a.e')); // null
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1182959/2659 тут ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result.push(get(value)); // сколько параметров должно быть у функции get?
```

```js
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 'c',
    },
  },
  d: 'd',
};

const get = (obj, str, def = null) => {
  let arrFromStr = str.split('.');
  for (let i = 0; i < arrFromStr.length; i++) {
    obj = obj[arrFromStr[i]];
    if (obj === undefined || obj === null)
      return def;
  }
  return obj;
};

console.log(get(obj, 'a.b.c')); // 'c'
console.log(get(obj, 'a.c', 0)); // 0
console.log(get(obj, 'a.e')); // null
```